# Create a Marquee in html

Tags: html, marquee

I want to Create a Marquee that when text Exit from one Side and show on other side

like i have code something like that

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1.5">Hello World</marquee>
```

Its shows Hello World move from left to right when first letter hide that it enters left side then i want that i doesn't hide it begin again from left side. Like H hide from left then H shows at right side.

Comment: You cannot influence the behavior of a marquee very precisely, because it is up to the displaying browser how it implements this. A browser may also not animate this at all. Have a look at some javascript animation techniques! Btw: aesthetically, i do not recommend using a marquee in any way, but that's my personal opinion.

Comment: There is also some css alrernative. The marquee tag is not part of any standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put

> marquee behavior="alternate">

to fix it...

Comment: Alternate Return back from same side but i want to come from other side from where it start.

Normally when whole text is gone then it come back from other side i want one letter gone it come on other and so with all text.

Comment: Check above site and there you can find all the alternates.

Comment: It won't help
they all are first vanish and then show//
thnx for help//

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <marquee behavior="alternate" >Heloo welcome</marquee>
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/XAzv5/

Comment: Alternate Return back from same side but i want to come from other side from where it start.

Normally when whole text is gone then it come back from other side i want one letter gone it come on other and so with all text.